Error while upgrade from Umbraco 14 to 15
I tried to upgrade my website from Umbraco 14 to 15.
This the error I get when try to navigate to my website after I did dotnet publish and copied bin\Release\net9.0\publish\ to ftp:
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

In Azure I changed .NET version from 8 to 9.
Any idea?
On local I was able to upgrade quickly and with no issues. But when deployed to Azure I can't access.
I tried to look in the KUDU console in Azure but it's not even give the latest updates. It's has logs from few months ago.
When upgraded, obviously I deleted all files of U14, stopped the app, then copied the files of U15.
Please advise.
Thanks.

Please share the error logs from the Log Stream.

How are you deploying your app to Azure?

how do I find the log stream? in the kudu console I see errors from months ago, I was trying to find the error, all I get is the "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

through ftp. doing dotnet publish on local, then copy bin\Release\net9.0\publish\ to ftp

Here you can find logs.

Please provide your kudu files image.

Change the stdoutLogEnabled value to true in the web.config file and then check the error log in the log files.

I created a sample Umbraco 14 application with .NET Core 8 and deployed it to Azure. Then, I upgraded it to Umbraco 15 with .NET Core 9 and redeployed it to Azure.
I upgraded my app by changing the  TargetFramework  to  net9.0  and updating  Umbraco.Cms  to version  15.0.0  in the  .csproj  file.
Below is my complete  .csproj  file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net9.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Umbraco.Cms" Version="15.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ICU.ICU4C.Runtime" Version="72.1.0.3" />
    <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.AppLocalIcu" Value="72.1.0.3" Condition="$(RuntimeIdentifier.StartsWith('linux')) or $(RuntimeIdentifier.StartsWith('win')) or ('$(RuntimeIdentifier)' == '' and !$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('osx')))" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>  <CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>true</CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
  <RazorCompileOnBuild>false</RazorCompileOnBuild>  <RazorCompileOnPublish>false</RazorCompileOnPublish>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>


Make sure to run the build and publish commands after upgrading to Umbraco 15.
If you are using a local database, upgrade it to Azure SQL Database.
Refer this  MSDoc  to Migrate Database to Azure SQL Database.
Below is my Connection String In  appsetting.json:
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "umbracoDbDSN": "Server=tcp:<ServerName>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<DataBaseName>;User ID=<UserName>@<ServerName>;Password=<Password>",
    "umbracoDbDSN_ProviderName": "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient"
  }


Before Deploying to my App to Azure I Changed the  .NET version  to  .NET9(STS)  in Configuration Section of Azure Web App.

After Successful deployed to Azure Using FTP, I got the same issue. When I checked the Kudu console, I found that my deployed files were stored in the  wwwroot/publish  folder.

I’ve changed the path mapping from  site/wwwroot  to  site/wwwroot/publish  in Configuration section of Azure Web App as shown below.

Azure Output:


Thanks! it works now. I enabled the log stream, the saw that the problem was indeed the path. I changed as you suggested the Physical Path from site\wwwroot to site and it works now. Thanks again

@Menahem Gil Glad it worked!
